# Combining 'depth' with 'include' in wp_list_pages()

Tags: pages, navigation, sub-menu, child-pages, wp-list-pages

I am using `wp_list_pages` to display my navigation that contains only specific top-level pages using the `include` parameter.

However, I would like to display the child pages of those top-level pages.

I would have thought this would be possible with:

`<?php wp_list_pages('title_li&depth=2&include=8,12,16,20,10,14'); ?>`

But it doesn't appear to work. If I remove the `include` parameter then it seems to work fine, but then it pulls in every page on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine WordPress mustn't allow that, so I ended up going with `exclude` instead

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li&depth=2&exclude=4,214,18'); ?>
```